# How can I start the Python debugger from the command line without a script argument?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I'd like to poke around with some Python syntax, but don't want to write a full script. In Perl I would say

```
perl -demo
```

What's the equivalent in Python?

The easiest I've found is

```
python -im pdb /dev/null
```

but that seems long-winded, especially when showing someone else.

Edit1:

For those confused about the debugger, here is the help after invoking it as above:

```
> pydemo
> /dev/null(1)<module>()
(Pdb) h

Documented commands (type help <topic>):
========================================
EOF    bt         cont      enable  jump  pp       run      unt   
a      c          continue  exit    l     q        s        until 
alias  cl         d         h       list  quit     step     up    
args   clear      debug     help    n     r        tbreak   w     
b      commands   disable   ignore  next  restart  u        whatis
break  condition  down      j       p     return   unalias  where 

Miscellaneous help topics:
==========================
exec  pdb

Undocumented commands:
======================
retval  rv
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you just want to poke around with some Python syntax? or do you actually *need* the debugger for that? are you debugging a script? Please explain how this is related to using a debugger.

Comment: @shx2 (long overdue): The debugger has ^^^ All those commands available. But specifically, `debug` and `pp` are my first touches. The behaviour of the REPL invoked from just `python` is a bit different, though to be sure, it's easier to enter multiline code in `python` than the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the Python IDLE and import pdb like so. From the command line, open the IDLE with `python` and then import pdb like you would any other module with `import pdb`. You can then test some snippet of code with `pdb.run('ENTER CODE SNIPPET HERE')`.

Comment: How is that shorter than the example I gave?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the `pdb` command direcly (not using `python -m pdb`), which is shorter:

```
% pdb /dev/null
```

If all you want is "to poke around with some Python syntax", you don't need a debugger for that, just run `python`:

```
% python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
>>> print "That was easy!"
That was easy!
>>>
```

You might be also be interested in using [`ipython`](https://ipython.org/), which is a very popular, feature-rich, interactive python shell, and `ipdb` which is a pdb-like debugger with a bunch of `ipython` features.

Comment: That is not the debugger. See OP for additional info.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic, thanks. Unfortunately, even with the additional info, I still don't understand why this is related to debugging. I commented on the question to clarify.

Comment: @shx2 OK, that's short enough. However, the debugger comes with several commands that make even explicit syntax easier to work on, such as the pretty printer. And just firing it up, importing a class, creating an object, and putting a breakpoint in the class code are things you can't do in the plain interpreter.